# Why an object marked as final can be modified and call non-final method in Java?

Tags: java, android, immutability, final

I am new to Java and I am from C++ background.

I thought `final` in Java works just like `const` in C++ but I guess not.

Object initiated as `const` in C++, only can call `const` methods and cannot change fields in the object.

But in my code below, I am able to assign value in `pet`. i.e. `pet.id = new ObjectId(newPetId);`.

```
private void addPet() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    final Pet pet;

    try {
        // Locally add and save pet.
        pet = getPetFromUserInput();

    } catch (InvalidInputException e) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return;
    }

    pet.id = new ObjectId(); // Modify field member directly.
    pet.updateName("MyPet"); // Call non-final method.
}
```

Comment: final on an object means that the reference to the object cannot change, it doesn't mean the object itself cannot change. So, `pet` cannot be reassigned to a different value, but the name, or other attributes of pet, can be changed. But there's enough to read on this if you google for it.

Comment: @ErikPragt Thank you. Your explanation clarifies confusion I had.

Comment: Feel fret to post an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing Erik's answer in comments, I found an easy explanation for C++ programmers.

`Pet pet;` in Java is like `Pet* pet;` in C++.

`final Pet pet;` in Java is like `Pet * const pet;` in C++ which makes the pointer `const` but not the value itself.

Note that there is a subtle difference in Java and C++.

In C++, you have to assign a value when declaring a `const` variable but in Java, it lets you do it later but only once.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the keyword "final" simply means that once initialized, you cannot  change the value of the variable. 
for example,

```
final int x = 0;`
//You can't do this!!!
int x=5
```

It has nothing to do with that variable calling methods.

Comment: You cannot change the "reference" - there is a difference

Answer (score 0):

In java   "final" means this

1.If you use "final" before a class, then it means there is no chance to create subclass to that class.

```
public final class Person {
void getName() {

}
```

}

Then you can't create like this.

```
public class Man extends Person{
}
"The type Man cannot subclass the final class Person" will be shown
```

2. If you write "final" before a method then

   ```
   public  class Person {
   final void getName() {      
   }   
   }
   ```

Then you can create subclass to this Person class but you cant override the getName() in subclass.

```
public class Man extends Person{

@Override
void getName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.getName();
}

}

"Cannot override the final method from Person" will be shown.
```

3. If you write "final" before a variable in a class, then you can't alter the value of that variable

exammple:

```
public  class Person {
public final String name;
void getName() {

}   
}
```

then in subclass, you can't modify the value.

```
public class Man extends Person{

public void getName() {
    name = "child";
}

}
"The final field Person.name cannot be assigned" will be shown
```

all these will shown in compile time itself.

Hope this helps you.